# How to stop succeeding method calls executing if the current method call comes with an exception

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, exception, methods

From my main JAVA class I am calling several other method calls in an another class in which any of these method call can come up with an exception. I need to know the simplest way of programming to stop executing rest of the method calls, print an error message and continue the next iteration in the for loop if the current method call comes up with an exception.

Say my methods are defined in class - testConnection

Methods are denoted as A,B,C,D,E,F in class testConnection

Say my main class calling these methods as in below order.

```
for (int i =0; i<=5; i++) {
    testConnection.A();
    testConnection.B();
    testConnection.C();
    testConnection.D();
    testConnection.E();
    testConnection.F();    
}
```

For an example, if B method call comes up with an exception, I need to stop rest of the methods executing (C,D,E and F), print an error message and return to the for loop and continue the next iteration

Answer (score 1):

you should keep your code(Method calling) into try block and handle it into a catch block Like this.

```
for (int i =0; i<=5; i++) {
try{
testConnection.A();
            testConnection.B();
            testConnection.C();
            testConnection.D();
            testConnection.E();
            testConnection.F();    
        }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a try/catch inside the loop, this will cancel any other method calls in the same iteration but still continue the loop

```
for (int i = 0; I <= 5; i++) {
    try {
        testConnection.A();
        testConnection.B();
        testConnection.C();
        testConnection.D();
        testConnection.E();
        testConnection.F();    
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need details of the exception, you can put `e.printStackTrace();` inside the `catch` block.

Comment: @BillNaylor Sure but that is not what the question is about.

Comment: It would non-the less be useful for the OP to be able to deduce which of their methods was responsible for the exception.

Comment: That might be included in the message in the thrown exception, we don't know that. You're not wrong but again it is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

If any of your methods throws an exception the control will immediately come out unless you have specifically handled the exception. So if method B has thrown the exception in the method and it will stop executing subsequent methods. You can catch the exception in your parent method to handle gracefully.

In your example you can do the following:-

```
try {
    for (int i =0; i<=5; i++) {
     testConnection.A();
     testConnection.B();
     testConnection.C();
     testConnection.D();
     testConnection.E();
     testConnection.F();    
     }
}catch (Exception e){
System.out.println("Execution stopped mid way due to some error");
}
```

Assume method B has thrown some exception.

Comment: try catch can be moved inside for loop if you want to resume the loop